# How to highlight a cell color based on the color of different cell

Tags: excel-2007

I have an Excel file with so may columns done with conditional formatting based on the formulas / values.

But now I need help to color code a particular cell called "overall status" based on the different columns' color coding like as mentioned below.

Overall:

```
Green - When all are in Green
Yellow - When any one of above is in Yellow
Red - When any one of above is in Red
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a VBA solution? If not, you should move this to Superuser.com. It will be pretty hard to determine the display format of cells that have been coloured with different respective conditional formatting rules. **Colour is not data**. Use helper columns with real numeric values that represent the respective states (i.e. the assigned conditional formatting colours). Then you can just use formulas to evaluate these cells.